# Copying table data from one database to another based on where condition in the destination database

Tags: mysql, etl

I have two MySQL databases, DB1 and DB2. Both of the databases have different usernames and passwords. There is a table in DB1 with name table1, and I want to copy this `table1` from DB1 database to DB2 database.

I know I could do this with

```
mysqldump -u DB1USERNAME -h DB1HOST -p DB1PASSWORD DB1 table1 | mysql -u DB2USERNAME -h DB2HOST -p DB2PASSWORD DB2
```

I know I can conditionally dump data from the DB1 database to DB2 using a --where parameter to the mysqldump in the above like this,

```
mysqldump -u DB1USERNAME -h DB1HOST -p DB1PASSWORD DB1 table1 --where="some condition" | mysql -u DB2USERNAME -h DB2HOST -p DB2PASSWORD DB2
```

However, I want to do the copying based on a condition in the destination database DB2.

I want to copy the data from DB1 to DB2 only if the count in the table1 database DB2 is empty.

Both the databases are on the same mysql server

How is this possible?

Comment: It is not possible sing mysql only, unless the two databeses are in the same mysql server instance or you can use federated table engine to link the two instances up.

Comment: @Shadow The two database are in the same mysql server. How it would be possible then. ?

Comment: @Shadow Could you please help me understand why this is marked as a duplicate ? I know it is possible to copy, but, I want to do it based on a condition on the destination database. Are there are answers on the question that you have marked as a duplicate of ?